# How to upload artifacts to existing release?

Tags: github-actions

My workflow has automatic packaging and upload steps that package build artifacts and upload them to the workflow page. I also manually create releases.

I would like to do the following:
when I push to the tag that was created with a given release,
I would like to upload the zipped artifact file to that release, so users can download
the artifact. Any tips on how to do this ?

Here is my [build yaml](https://github.com/GrokImageCompression/grok/blob/67504f98a6b3e3bc4f06c10dc30436c0abfd085b/.github/workflows/build.yml) file.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how that did not work. Please don't paste links, but instead show a minimal reproducible example, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try using this action to achieve what you want?  https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-files-to-a-github-release

Comment: Thanks, @GuiFalourd, I will try this - looks promising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's dead simple to do this:

```
  - name: upload binaries to release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      if: ${{startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') }}
      with:
          files: build/FOO.zip
```

Answer (score 12):

It seems the action (softprops/action-gh-release@v1) mentioned also creates a release. But there is a much simpelere way upload an artifact to a release without the need of introducing action. The `gh cli` which is by default available on a GitHub hosted runners can upload the artifact for you.

```yaml
 assets:
    name: upload assets
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write # release changes require contents write

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Upload Release Asset
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run:
          gh release upload <release_tag> <a_file>
```

Checkout full release example [here](https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner/blob/main/.github/workflows/release.yml).